# Problem of choosing iterative ranges from for loop in variables

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a variable which has 20 observations. I need to values in range i:i+3. 4 values for each iteration.  For example
Code:

```
var1 <- 50:70
for (i in 1:3){
  print(var[i:i+3])
}
```

Expected result is:

```
[1] 50,51,52,53
[2] 51,52,53,54
[3] 52,53,54,55
```

But i can’t get expected result. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `()` to avoid the operator precedence in evaluation

```
for (i in 1:3){
    print(var1[i:(i+3)])
  }
```

-output

```
#[1] 50 51 52 53
#[1] 51 52 53 54
#[1] 52 53 54 55
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was about to go crazy. 